# Name Generator for .NET

Tags: .net, generator

Has anyone written, or know of a library, that generates fairly accurate looking Western European style names?  i.e. John, Susan, Smith, Julien, April, etc., etc...

Comment: A lot of answers reference the US Census data.  Here are the updated links:
Surnames (top 1000 and those used more than 100 times): http://www.census.gov/topics/population/genealogy/data/2000_surnames.html.  Top Names: National and state level Baby names by year of birth going back to the 1800's: http://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/limits.html.  CSV format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if this will work but check [FakeNameGenerator](http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/) it will generate names and some information as well. One at a time or in batch.

Answer (score 6):

I created a .net random name generating library (dll) that uses the data from the lists mentioned by HanClinto (ie the [US Census names list](http://www.census.gov/genealogy/names/names_files.html)).  It allows you to generate first and last names or only first or last names.  Also you can generate specifically male or female names or let it randomly determine the sex of the first name.

[You can try it out or download it at this blog post](http://www.markdavidrogers.com/random-name-generator-net-library/).

Answer (score 3):

I just grab the [US Census names list](http://www.census.gov/genealogy/names/names_files.html) and select from there randomly. The male list is only 41k -- not too big, especially when compressed a bit.

Answer (score 2):

If you are targeting a database, the [RedGate Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/SQL_Data_Generator/) is a good option.

Visual Studio Database Edition also has similar functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Jon Galloway wrote a post  on his blog about name generation - [Generate random fake surnames](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/code-puzzle-2-generate-random-fake-surnames)

Answer (score 1):

why not just grab a list of names and choose one randomly from the list? I'm doubtful that there'd be a particular way to 'generate' realistic names.

http://www.ssa.gov/OACT/babynames/

You *could* try using this list to produce a [Markov Chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain), which might yield some useful results.

Answer (score 1):

The only name-generator I know of used statistical analysis to analyse names, and created new ones based on that. [It wasn't exactly a 'library', but it had sample C++ code, along with the algorithm, which would probably only take an hour or two to implement; or you could compile it as C++/CLI](http://www.gamasutra.com/features/19990917/infinite_03.htm). The samples on the page was using an arbitrary text, but if you used a bunch of names, then I'm pretty sure that it would go well.